# Failing Upload Script

Tags: php, upload, uploading

I have a php script which I use it for uploads. Before I switched to another server, but now it doesn't. This is the PHP file:

```
<?php
if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
    echo "There was an error processing your upload. Please try again. ";
}else{
    // Save this file in the directory
    move_uploaded_file('$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]', '"uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]');
}
?>
```

I'm not only getting this error in error.log:

```
[Sun Jul 21 12:32:34 2013] [error] [client 10.127.2.10] PHP Warning:  

move_uploaded_file(uploads/file.
txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/liongold/Web/upload_script.php on line 6, referer
: http://url/upload_page.html
[Sun Jul 21 12:32:34 2013] [error] [client 10.127.2.10] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to mov
e '/tmp/phpa0hsMc' to 'uploads/file.txt' in /home/liongold/Web/upload_script.php on line 6, referer: h
ttp://url/upload_page.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This may because of permission problem. directory "uploads" must have write permission for upload to that directory.

Go to your control panel and set directory permission to 777.

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes 755 is also enough.